# On how many arbitrary constants do the families of function depend

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to learn about differential equations by doing some problem sheets online.

I found this exercise:
[image]

So in my opinion, the answer would be `0` for all the subpoints because the functions do not depend on the constants, only on the variables such as `x`.

However, the answer is this:

[image]

Any idea what this means?

Comment: The functions do depend on the constants !

Answer (score 0):

Take (a) for instance.  Let $f_1(x)=c_1e^{k_1x}$ and $f_2(x)=c_2e^{k_2x}$.  What you should think about is how to manipulate your constants so that $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$.  In (a) this is only ever possible if $c_1=c_2$ AND $k_1=k_2$.

On the other hand, take (b), where $f_1(x)=c_1e^{x+a_1}$ and $f_2(x)=c_2e^{x+a_2}$.  Recall you can write e^{x+a} as $e^ae^x$, so if $c_1e^{a_1}=c_2e^{a_2}$ then they will be equal - BUT in this case there's really only one free parameter:  we can define $k=ce^a$ as our "constant coefficient" for $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

For all $x$,

1.
$$ce^{kx}=c'e^{k'x}\iff\frac c{c'}e^{(k-k')x}=1.$$

This identity can only occur when $k-k'$ (to cancel the dependency on $x$), so that the equation simplifies to

$$\frac c{c'}=1$$ or $c=c'$.

This proves that all pairs $(c,k)$ define different functions, and there are two independent parameters.

2.
$$ce^{x+a}=c'e^{x+a'}\iff\frac c{c'}e^{a-a'}=1.$$

As $x$ does not appear in the identity, all pairs such that $ce^a=c'e^{a'}$ define the same function and there is actually only one independent parameter.

3.
$$c_1+c_2\cos 2x+c_3\cos^2x=c'_1+c'_2\cos 2x+c'_3\cos^2x\iff\\ c_1-c'_1+(c_2-c'_2)\cos 2x+(c_3-c'_3)\cos^2x=0.$$

But we need to notice the identity $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1$ and the previous relation becomes

$$c_1-c'_1+2(c_2-c'_2)\cos^2x-(c_2-c'_2)+(c_3-c'_3)\cos^2x=0.$$

We can regroup as

$$c_1-c_2-c'_1+c'_2+(2c_2+c_3-2c'_2-c'_3)\cos^2x=0$$ and we only have two independent constants, say

$$c_4:=c_1-c_2,\\c_5:=2c_2+c_3.$$

4.

Hint: you can pull any factor from the logarithm to turn it to an additive constant.